# Simplify the sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Consider the sum of two polynomials
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {{{n-1} \choose {k}}^2 z^{2k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} {{n-2} \choose {k}} {{n} \choose {k+1}} z^{2k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}a_i z^i.
$$
I want to find the exact expression for $a_i$. Of course I may divide  it into even and odd parts but I hope  there is a formula for $a_i$ .

Comment: Do you mean for n'th term of the series on RHS?

Comment: From your expression the $a_i$'s are simply $\binom{n-1}{i/2}^2$if $i$ is even and $\binom{n-2}{(i-1)/2}\binom{n}{(i+1)/2}$ when $i$ is odd

Comment: @Alex,   yes and without piecewise expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A sum $A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kz^k$ can be split into *even* and *odd* parts via
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}\left(A(z)+A(-z)\right)
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kz^k+\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_k(-z)^k\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}a_kz^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^na_{2k}z^{2k}
> \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}\left(A(z)-A(-z)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}a_kz^k
> =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{2k+1}z^{2k+1}
> \end{align*}

Therefore the LHS of your expression can be written as

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}^2&z^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}\binom{n}{k+1}z^{2k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}\left(\binom{n-1}{k}^2\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}
+\binom{n-2}{k}\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\right)z^k
\end{align*}

and could now be transformed in order to find a convenient representation.

*Note:* On your RHS you could replace the upper bound of the sum with $2n-2$.

Comment: @Leox: You're welcome! :-)